# Why ios in-app applicationUserName is always null? What's wrong?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

The code is:

```
  {
    SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    payment.applicationUserName = @"data";
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
  }
  ... ...
handle purchased:
  {
    NSString *appUserName = transaction.payment.applicationUserName; 
    // !!! The appUserName is always null...
  }
```

the applicationUserName is always null when purchased state. Does anyone point out what I did wrong?
i use sandbox account, xcode 12.1, ios 14.1
I have researched some analogous questions, but no help to me.
Appreciate for any help!

Comment: Did you read the duplicates on your original question?  This field is not supplied to you. It is something you supply to Apple to help them with fraud detection in their backend. The value you supply is an opaque hash linked to your users account, not the actual user name.

Comment: Thank you very much,  Paulw11. I have read your previous reply, but that didn't seem to help me. I understand applicationUserName is not the actual user name.I append my game player account id, game server id and game role id into a string value, then assign to applicationUserName variable.So i can know ship to which one when purchased state.As far as i know, Normally this happens only occasionally that the applicationUserName may be nil, but it's always null in my case.So I am confused.In my limited experience with ios in-app purchase, if i did something wrong?

Comment: You cannot rely on this property having a value in the purchased state, and indeed it almost certainly won't. You shouldn't need this property to have a value; you already have the user details since you have submitted the payment request.

Comment: I am very glad you can reply me, Paulw11.I understand what you said, and that's what the official said.But there is a situation that player may switch another role or quit game before get purchased state.In this case, i can't guarantee send product to correct role, because an account can have multiple roles in my game.Like google in-app purchase, it will return the custom data which i put into when buy period correctly, so i can send product to correct role.Now, what should i do about Apple in-app purchase?Does it only    be allowed to drop orders?

Comment: You simply assign the purchase to the user that is signed in when the payment is processed. In 99.999% of the time I would expect that the payment goes through in a few seconds  and the user would not have an opportunity  to log in to a different account.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, Paulw11.So far it can only be so. :)